# How to add click event to a-image in ar-js

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am trying to add click event to a-image tag but I not able to do so. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add

```
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('clickhandler', {
        init: function() {
            this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                alert('Clicked!')
            });
    }});
</script>
```

and add `clickhandler` attributes to your a-image, like
`<a-image clickhandler ... >`

Source: https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/location-based/click-places/index.html

Comment: https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js---
https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.7.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js--

Code -------
  <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled:false;' renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true">

                    <a-marker class="qr-marker" type='pattern' url='/patt_files/1.patt'>
                <a-entity clickhandler gltf-model="/images/ar-models/1.glb"></a-entity>
            </a-marker>

                <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
-----
used these lib. and when I tap on the model. its not working.